# Use of that box

Tags: meaning

> Fidel Castro sent me that box ofHavana cigars last week," says Oscar Niemeyer, looking dapper in blue linen trousers and black shirt with silver buttons.

What does ”that box” mean in this sentence ? Does it mean ; he sent me cigars as much as amount in this box? Is “that” in this sentence used to describe the amount of cigars? I mean; If I say ;

> I need that box of sugar

would it mean I need sugar as much as amout in that box?

Comment: He means an actual box that he is pointing to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is implied that Oscar Niemeyer is speaking to a journalist. "That" is used to refer to objects that are not close to the speaker. It just means that the box is either close to the journalist, or at least not close to the Oscar Niemeyer.

The word "that" makes no reference to the number of cigars.

If you say "I need that box of sugar" there must be a box, and the box must be close to the person you are talking to, or at least far from you.

```
 O -"that box"         o
/|\                   /|\
/ \           [|||]   / \
Oscar          box     journalist
```

Comment: Then If I say I need sugar as much as amount in that box I would talk about amount of sugar and if I say I need that box of sugar I would talk about a box which contains sugar.

Comment: Yes, certainly if you talk about "that box of sugar" you are talking about a box.  The first sentence is wrong. You should say "I want as much sugar as would fit into that box". But the expression is such an odd thing to ask, I doubt anyone actually says it.

Comment: The sentence "I need sugar as much as amount in that box" in not grammatical for the same reason that "I need sugar 5 kg" is not grammatical.  A grammatically correct sentence could be "I need as much sugar as the amount in this box" However the sentence is odd: This is not how we specify the amount of sugar that we need.

Comment: Actually I wrote that sentence by thinking ... sugar(that is ) as much as...